# Got Permission denied: connect while opening stream

Tags: java, stream, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a strange behaviour with a java client that uses webservice stubs generated by wsimport.

The client says sth about

```
Got Permission denied: connect while opening stream from http://dev:8080/LicenseServer/services/ServerImpl?wsdl
```

But I can open the URL in my webbrowser and the wsdl shows up correctly. Also I can control the Soap11Binding/HttpSoap11Endpoint from my browser.

A hint maybe is that the hostname "dev" is resolved by C:\Windows\System32\driver\etc\hosts.

Running the java-client from within the same network as the server makes no trouble.

Maybe the stub's initialization process relies on a "real" DNS resolution of the hostname?

Comment: Hello everybody! This problem was not related to jax-ws or wsdl. It was merely the fact that jre7 and ipv6stacks wont come together on most hardware. See also https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2395610 or http://jonathangiles.net/blog/?p=1126 I solved it by putting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to my VM arguments :)